# Secure site for members

Tags: login, acl

any way to auto display login form on each page when user not logged in. I couldnt find any suitable answer for this.I have to create a membership site but when I change access of articles to specified group it just displays Not Authorized error, instead i would like  a login form.Any work arounds?

Comment: Thanks @johnny_s, please provide this comment as an answer so this question can be resolved.

Comment: No problem @NeilRobertson - done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a login module and set the viewing access level to 'guests'.

Link here [docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial)